# OpenCV compilation error in eclipse

Tags: opencv

I have been coding in python before and included the library of openCV without any problem. Now, I want to code in C++ so I downloaded eclipse and openCV libraries and included their path in the includes from eclipse ..

I have simple example of openCV and I am trying to run it, but I get this error -->

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Example ****
```

make all 
Building file: ../Test.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Test.d" -MT"Test.d" -o "Test.o" "../Test.cpp"
Finished building: ../Test.cpp

Building target: Example
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "Example"  ./Test.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
./Test.o: In function `gh::main()':
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:16: undefined reference to`cvCreateImage'
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:21: undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:22: undefined reference to`cvShowImage'
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:23: undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:24: undefined reference to`cvDestroyWindow'
/home/shamma/workspace/Example/Debug/../Test.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Example] Error 1enter code here

any idea what might be the cause of the problem, I have tried lots of things without use

thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know the problem might be in your code. Do you have a `main()` function in Test.cpp ? You must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not properly configured OpenCV libraries. I recommend you to follow the [OpenCV tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) to start using it with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to project->properties->settings  and under GCC C++ linker-> libraries and assuming you're just testing, add "opencv_core" and "opencv_highgui"  there are many more and for each library you need to manually include them so that eclipse can tell the compiler to link these libraries when you run your program.

Also as a note generally "cvE______" is opencv for C where as for C++ it would be cv::E____ , its really confusing that sometime you can get away with both, but not always, so stick the the function in the namespace without cv prefixes.